# Camel binding mode for JSON not working, cant unmarshal it to POJO

Tags: json, rest, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm trying to send message from rest API to new route, and even thou I receive request in JSON format on my REST API and binding is set to JSON, when I forward it to new route it will be shown as InputStream and I will have to marshal it to JSON in order to use it.

I already tried using streamCaching and other components in RestConfiguration (consumes, produces, type, dataType). Also i'm using all dependencies in POM.

```
public void configure() {
    restConfiguration().component("servlet")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
            .skipBindingOnErrorCode(false);

    rest("/resttest")
       .patch("/t1")
            .id("t1")
            .description("t1")
            .consumes("application/json")
            .produces("application/json")
            .param()
                .name("body")
               .type(RestParamType.body)
               .dataType("json")
                .required(true)
            .endParam()
            .to("direct:test2");
```

This route is in other class:

```
 from("direct:test2").id("test2")

            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson,SomePOJO.class)
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, SomePOJO.class)
            .choice()
            .when(simple("${body.getStatus()} =~ 'Closed'"))
            .....
```

I was expecting to get JSON message on test2 route, and somehow I get InputStream, so i have to do marshaling first. Anybody know how I can make REST API forward me to route message in JSON format, not as stream?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
```

before your unmarshal.

Comment: Not sure how that would help?
But I tried it and its not working.

I know problem is somewhere in REST API, since its not binding received message to JSON, hence message in $body is in InputStream format.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and I had to apply the marshal method for incoming values and unmarshal method for response.

This was the response in postman:
[image]

And I was using this code:

```
rest(service.service)
.description(ContentCategory.api("Service Test"))           
.post("/product/{productType}/{enterpriseId}")
.description("service for saving a product")
.consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.type(Product.class)
.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
.produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.outType(String.class)
.route()
.bean("productService", "saveProduct")
.marshal()
.json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.endRest();
```

I just added the unmarshall method after realizing that I was receiving an InputStream

```
rest(service.service)
.description(ContentCategory.api("Service Test"))           
.post("/product/{productType}/{enterpriseId}")
.description("service for saving a product")
.consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.type(Product.class)
.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
.produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.outType(String.class)
.route()
.bean("productService", "saveProduct")
.marshal()
.json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
.unmarshal()
.json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.endRest();
```

In fact, I just added this two lines

```
.unmarshal()
.json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
```

And it starts working:
[image]

It think is probably you need to use the unmarshal method for the resttest service.